# Is it customary to have one "main" method call in a python script?

Tags: python

Sort of a weird question, but I was wondering if there was some sort of Python standard regarding function calls. It's possible to call every function just in the body of a Python script (I don't know if there is a more accurate term for everything outside of a function) but I didn't know if I should be putting all of the function calls into a main-like function.

Basically, is one of the following examples more correct than the other?

1:

```
def foo():
    pass

def bar():
    pass

foo()
bar()
```

2:

```
def foo():
    pass
def bar():
    pass
def main():
    foo()
    bar()

main()
```

Hopefully my question was clear enough, thanks for any answers!

Comment: It really depends on your style. If your "main" workflow has many (define it as you will) function calls, then it helps to have one function (`main`) to encapsulate all that. As a side note, you typically want to put that call in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block

Comment: It completely depends what's in the file. It could be a bunch of helper/utility functions in which case there'd be no apparent reason to blindly call all the functions.

Comment: The main benefit of defining `main`, rather than putting "loose" code under the `if __name__...` block is to have an entry point you can unit-test.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I guess I have seen this mostly in code by those who are more used to C/C++, and even in books that included lots non-pythonic idioms. As Python became popular, too many fresh converts wrote books too soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just write a python file that is supposed to run by itself, you can just call all the functions like in your first example.

However, if your file could eventually get imported into another file, you usually don't want all those methods to be called upon import, only when you directly run that file. For that reason most developers write a `main` function that contains stuff for direct execution, and wrap it inside this construct:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This ensures that nothing gets executed if you import your file (because `__name__` won't be `__main__`). You can also just write your method calls in that if-statement, but this is how most people do it

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, just the typical call is usually in an `if` block, like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This prevents `main` from being called when the module is imported and not run directly.